# Is there a way to always avoid a page break when a section is followed by a subsection?

Tags: page-breaking

## Question

Can I force LaTeX to always keep a section with a subsection on the same page if there is nothing in between?

## Situation

Let's suppose I have a section called `\section{All About Monkeys}` and a `subsection{Introduction}` following it. How can I ensure that there will never be a page break between the two?

## Example

Here is an example of my situation. Perhaps it could be further minimized. `tikz, tikzlibrary, anyfontsize` are all used by `titlesec`. Thanks to Werner, I also included `hyperref`, because it also affects the section spacing.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage{needspace}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}

\newcommand{\tikzsectitle}[1]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,baseline,every node/.style={inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt}]
    \path let \p1=($ (titlenumber.east)-(titlenumber.west) $)
    in
    node [text width=\textwidth-\x1,align=left] (titletext) {#1\strut};
\end{tikzpicture}%
}%
\newcommand{\tikzsecnumber}[1]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,baseline,every node/.style={inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt}]
    \node [font=\fontsize{60}{70}\selectfont,align=left] (titlenumber) {\makebox[1em][l]{#1}};
\end{tikzpicture}%
}%
\newcommand{\tikztitleline}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,every node/.style={inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt}]
    \draw ([yshift=-0ex]titletext.south west) -- ([yshift=-0ex]titletext.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}%

% TITLE FORMATTING
\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\needspace{8cm}\sffamily\color{blue}\Huge\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\tikzsecnumber{\thesection}\tikzsectitle{#1}\tikztitleline{}}
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{40pt}{5ex plus .2ex}
% SUBSECTION
\titleformat{\subsection}[hang]{\needspace{6cm}\color{blue!85}\Large\bfseries}{\thesubsection\quad}{0pt}{#1}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}


\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
Monkeys are haplorhine (dry-nosed) primates, a group generally possessing tails and consisting of approximately 260 known living species. Many monkey species are tree-dwelling (arboreal), although there are species that live primarily on the ground, such as baboons. 
\section{All About Monkeys}
\subsection{Introduction}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

### Output

The following is an example of what should never occur:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Let's suppose we have a minimal example... yes. You're talking about sectional units, influenced by many packages. Please provide us with something to work with, even if it doesn't use any packages...

Comment: ...note that, by default, this doesn't happen.

Comment: I am working on the example now...I have several things to consider. I am using `titlesec`, `needspace`, and I have some weird `tikz` things going on in the sectioning commands. I think I will leave out the `tikz` if that is ok.

Comment: I think latex never break page with just section title in the last line.

Comment: Just as long as we can reproduce your problem. Don't forget to also mention if you're using [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) - it also plays a part in sectional units.

Comment: It is tricky to get this thing to reproduce my problem, because I am not allowed to use my original text. I will keep trying until I get it and post the code thereafter. (I am using `hyperref`--nice of you to mention that ;)

Comment: Apart from anything else, why have you got the massive amount of forced space (`\needspace`) it the titles? If I remove that the issue goes away: not really that much of a surprise given the affect it will have on the layout.

Comment: Ah, I think that was left over from an initial attempt to fix the problem. It was originally at 6cm (also significant). I usually want the section to start a new page. There are some occasions where the sections are very short and they may be on the same page. Normally, this should be avoided (hence the large forced space).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\needspace` commands are part of the problem but the real culprit is the `\color`-command which inserts a whatsit. Either add a `\nopagebreak` or use the solution from egreg here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/101643/2388

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage{needspace}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}

\newcommand{\tikzsectitle}[1]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,baseline,every node/.style={inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt}]
    \path let \p1=($ (titlenumber.east)-(titlenumber.west) $)
    in
    node [text width=\textwidth-\x1,align=left] (titletext) {#1\strut};
\end{tikzpicture}%
}%
\newcommand{\tikzsecnumber}[1]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,baseline,every node/.style={inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt}]
    \node [font=\fontsize{60}{70}\selectfont,align=left] (titlenumber) {\makebox[1em][l]{#1}};
\end{tikzpicture}%
}%
\newcommand{\tikztitleline}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,every node/.style={inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt}]
    \draw ([yshift=-0ex]titletext.south west) -- ([yshift=-0ex]titletext.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}%

% TITLE FORMATTING
\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\sffamily\color{blue}\Huge\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\tikzsecnumber{\thesection}\tikzsectitle{#1}\tikztitleline{}}
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{40pt}{5ex plus .2ex}
% SUBSECTION
\titleformat{\subsection}[hang]{\color{blue!85}%\nopagebreak %<--uncomment
\Large\bfseries}{\thesubsection\quad}{0pt}{#1}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}


\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-3]a\\b\\c\\d\\e\\f
\section{All About Monkeys}
\subsection{Introduction}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: `needspace` is an essential part of my workflow by the way.

Comment: Well needspace inserts break points. So if you use it in the `\subsection` command is will allow a break before the `\subsection`. If you really think you need it in the `\subsection` try `\if@nobreak\else\needspace{6cm}\fi` (don't forget `\makeatletter`) so that it doesn't is inserted if there is a `\section` directly before.